# How to pass a shell variable to awk in Bourne shell?

Tags: awk, sh

I'm a newbie to Bourne shell and want to do simple array simulation. This works:

```
COLORS='FF0000 0000FF 00FF00'
i=2
color=$(echo ${COLORS} | awk '{print $2}')
echo "color selected: $color"
```

What I want to do is to pass `$i` instead of the fixed `$2` parameter in print (this will later be used in a loop). I spent hours figuring out the right combination of single and double quotes to do this, no luck.

The closest I got is

```
color=$("echo ${COLORS} | awk '{print "$"${i}}'")
```

The run result is:

```
+ COLORS=FF0000 0000FF 00FF00
+ i=2
+ echo FF0000 0000FF 00FF00 | awk '{print $2}'
./tempgraph.sh: ./tempgraph.sh: 37: echo FF0000 0000FF 00FF00 | awk '{print $2}': not found
+ color=
+ echo color selected:
color selected:
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
color=$(echo ${COLORS} | awk "{print \$$i}")
```

If you use `'...'`, the content is not expanded. But you want the value of `$i` inserted in your script. So `"..."` is to be used, which does variable expanding. But you also want a `$` in front of the number for AWK, so you've got to escape it (`\$`).

Comment: Thank you! It works well, although I'm not sure I understand quotes better. One would think that the double quotes are eaten up by the shell after expanding stuff in it, but it seems they are also get passed to awk.

Comment: They *are* eaten by the shell, but so are the single quotes. Both enclose a string. For example, usually `foo a b` passes `a` as first argument to `foo`, and `b` as second argument. But with `foo "a b"` the shell passes `a b` as the only argument to `foo`. The big difference between the single and double quotes is that with double quotes, you can "embedd" other stuff, like variables: if you do pass `'$i'` as an argument, really the string `$i` gets passed. But with `"$i"`, the content of the variable `i` is passed.

Answer (score 5):

Don't waste your time trying to get the shell to expand the variable correctly in the awk command, just define a variable using `-v`:

```
echo $COLORS | awk -v col=2 '{ print $col }'
```

In terms of your `i` variable, this becomes:

```
i=1
echo $COLORS | awk -v col=$i '{ print $col }'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I accepted the other answer because it may help other people struggling with shell quoting.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get at your environment directly:

```
export COLORS='FF0000 0000FF 00FF00'
awk 'END {split(ENVIRON["COLORS"],colors);for(col in colors) { print "Color",col,"is",colors[col]}}' /dev/null
```

which gives the following output on this mac:

```
Color 2 is 0000FF
Color 3 is 00FF00
Color 1 is FF0000
```

Comment: You can also get at `i` in the same way, either by `export i` or by calling awk with `i=1 awk ...`.

Comment: Exactly.  This helps to avoid the quoting problem and lets you grab an arbitrary number of values out of your environment.

This is what's great about Unix™: We have multiple ways to get the relevant information into the program.

Answer (score 1):

Variables assigned on invokation like `-v foo=bar` are available in the `BEGIN` where variable assigned with a simple `baz=qux` are not.

```
BEGIN { print foo, bar; }
{ print foo, bar; }
```

see the difference:

```
echo Don\'t Panic! | awk -f ./hello.awk -v foo=Hello bar=World
Hello
Hello World
```